# JDO Query ordering issue

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I have a JDO query which filters on two properties of a "Person" entity, lets call them "age" and "height". I wish to order the results by the Persons "score". However, due to the restrictions App Engine imposes I firstly have to order by age or height. So I currently have

```
query.setOrdering("age desc, score asc");
```

I am really not interested in the results being ordered by age, I just have to include that for the query to work (as I have filtered on age), I really just need the results ordered by score.

Is there a way to get the results ordered by score and effectively ignore the age ordering?

Thanks

Comment: Other than removing the ordering completely, and sort the results in memory, I don't see any solution.

Comment: In that case is there any way of setting the importance of the ordering I.e. order by score and then age rather than the other way around?

Comment: No. http://code.google.com/intl/fr/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries.html#Restrictions_on_Queries says : "If a query has both a filter with an inequality comparison and one or more sort orders, the query must include a sort order for the property used in the inequality, and the sort order must appear before sort orders on other properties."

Comment: Yeah I read that, I was clutching on to false hope that someone may have a solution to this annoying restriction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't order by score first since no index could support that query.

The solution/workaround I've seen recommended is to pick a few pre-defined age ranges, pre-compute each `Person`s membership to those ranges, and then use an equality filter on that membership so you can sort by `score`.

For example, if you picked "<13", "13-18", and "18+" as your age ranges, you'd add three boolean properties to each `Person`.  Then you could do a query like "select * from Person where isUnder13 = true order by score".  I guess in this case since membership is mutually exclusive you could use a single enum property and search for something like `ageRange = 'UNDER_13'`, which would cut down on the number of indexes built.

Of course, this means you can't have an arbitrary search function... but having fewer choices isn't always bad for user experience.